# ExoPlayer prepare source from byte arrays

Tags: android

I'm working with ExoPlayer. I figured out that **ByteArratDataSource** is used to prepare the video from **byte[]** but still don't know how to use it. Normally, i use **Uri** to prepare the source

```
private void initPlayer() {
    ...
    DataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(
            context,
            Util.getUserAgent(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)));


    MediaSource currentMediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
            .createMediaSource(songUri);


    simpleExoPlayer.prepare(currentMediaSource, false, true);
}
```

But now i have a byte data source, how can i use it, i didn't find any guide on this site about the byte data https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html. Please help me. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your `byte[]` comes from a file, there is an easier way to play the file than to use `ByteArrayDataSource`. `ExtractorMediaSource` using the `DefaultDataSource` can play data from a local file.

From the [docs](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/upstream/DefaultDataSource.html):

> For fetching data from a local file (e.g. file:///path/to/media/media.mp4, or just /path/to/media/media.mp4 because the implementation assumes that a URI without a scheme is a local file URI).

Simply pass the path of the file as the URI to `createMediaSource`.

<strike>Regarding `ByteArrayDataSource`, it looks like you simply pass the bytes into the constructor:

`byte[] bytes;
DataSource byteArrayDataSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(bytes);`</strike>

And then pass `byteArrayDataSource` to `ExtractorMediaSource.Factory` as normal. Of course, since most video files are large, this needs to be used with care so as to not use excessive RAM. One of the other [DataSources](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/upstream/DataSource.html) is prefered.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can not do `DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new ByteArrayDataSource(bytes);` It must be `ByteArrayDataSource dataSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(bytes);` However, it got crashed at the above code line.

Comment: Yes, you are correct it should be `DataSource` instead of `DataSourceFactory`. Corrected

Comment: @CallmeK, knowledge of that crash would be helpful in answering your question. Could you add the description of that crash to your question including any error messages in logcat?

Comment: I fixed that crash. However, `MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(factory).createMediaSource(uri);` the `createMediaSource` only accept the **Uri** not the **DataSource**. I also tried `DataSource dataSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(bytes)` <------- this worked fine, it returned something like `com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.ByteArrayDataSource@f013ca4`. But `dataSource.getUri()` was **null**